# Resizing a React navigation bar component when width is reduced?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, frontend

I have a navigation bar for my webapp with the following css setup:

```
.navigation {
    background: white;
    display: flex;
    height: 5em;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 2em;
    color: blue;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.075em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;}
```

My issue is on mobile, my tabs in the navigation bar get all squeezed together. Is there a way in React that I can detect the width of the page and collapse all my navigation tabs into a dropdown menu? Or is this a CSS thing?

Comment: This is a css thing. With css it is quite straightforward to use flexbox, max- min-width, @media settings etc to make this work. To make React a) aware of the width and b) apply styling based on width, requires a lot of trickery. In general, use css for styling, use react for HTML structure + logic.

Comment: I am planning on going the CSS route to fix this. I am relatively new at this so I am not sure about the parameters you mentioned. Does flexbox allow for a quick-fix?

Comment: try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-nav-bar as navigation bar its kinda nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seriously, your best option is css. Let react focus on the **structure** of your DOM and on the interaction. Let css take care of **styling**.

So you can keep your react code simple like this:

```
render() {
  var myMenu = ['Home','Settings','About us', 'Other stuff'];
  return (
    <div>
      <button className='hamburger'>m</button>
      <ul className='menu'>
        {myMenu.map(item => {
          return <MenuItem key={item} text={item}/>
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>    
  );
}
```

And do the styling stuff in css (code below with Sass):

```
ul.menu
  position: absolute
  display: flex
  flex-direction: row
  width: 100%

li.menu-item
  flex: 1 0 auto
  padding: 10px
  margin: 2px
  background-color: grey
  text-align: center

li.menu-item:hover
  background-color: blue

button.hamburger
  display: none
  padding: 10px
  margin: 2px
  background-color: grey

@media screen and (max-width : 760px)
  ul.menu
    flex-direction: column
    display: none

  li.menu-item
    background-color: orange

  button.hamburger
    display: block
    position: absolute

  button.hamburger:focus + ul.menu
    display: flex
```

You can find a [working demo in codepen here](http://codepen.io/wintvelt/pen/BKGaKY?editors=0100).

Comment: button.hamburger:focus + ul.menu
Is this a SASS thing? I currently use just CSS and was wondering if there was a solution like this with CSS?

Comment: The "+" is plain CSS. It means "followed by", so button with focus followed by ul is the selector, and ul gets the styling.

Answer (score 5):

You could handle this in CSS, using proper media queries.

But if you prefer to do it with React, here is how you can implement it, listening to the window "resize" event:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            layoutMode: this.getLayoutMode(),
        };
        this.onResize = this.onResize.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
    }

    onResize() {
        this.setState({
            layoutMode: this.getLayoutMode(),
        });
    }

    getLayoutMode() {
        return window.innerWidth > 1000 ?
            'desktop'
            : 'mobile';
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.layoutMode === 'desktop' ? (
            <NavigationBar />
        ) : (
            <DropdownMenu />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it out and it works well. However, as you mentioned, you said you can handle it in CSS? What method would this be? Am I making a rookie mistake with my settings?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render a drop-down menu on mobile, here's one strategy:

1. Listen for media query changes in React: http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Using-media-queries-in-JavaScript-AbsurdJS-edition.
2. Use that listener to update `this.state` on the component (ex: `this.state.isMobile`).
3. Render different Navigation components based on the media query conditional (ex: `this.state.isMobile ? <Navigation type="mobile" /> : <Navigation type="desktop" />`).